# __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'content_type' whle trying to render image dynamically

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, html5-video, httpresponse

I am trying to render Image dynamically ( Live video streaming). but i am seeing error

> ```
>   __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'content_type'
> ```

My `Url.py`

```
url(r'^live$',views.video_feed,name='live'),
```

`View.py`

```
def gen(webcam):
        while True:
          frame = webcam.get_frame()
           yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

def video_feed(request):
        return HttpResponse(request,"clients/live.html",{'live_feed':gen(webcam())},content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

`cam.py`  ( It fetches frames and return frames to generator function)

```
class webcam(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, './clients/static/clients/live/')
    self.frames = open(self.file_path + 'live' + '.jpg', 'rb').read()

    def get_frame(self):
        return self.frames
```

please advise what am i missing

Comment: You probably want to use `render` and not `HttpResponse` in `def video_feed`.

Comment: i am new to django. could you please help me with code for render

Comment: What I was suggesting was really just replacing `HttpResponse` with `render`, because it seems the arguments you are passing are appropriate for [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). You have to import it: `from django.shortcuts import render`.

Comment: finally i got the solution. i should be using return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(cam(url,cam_type)),content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')